# Core Service to publish pages in a structure group in SDL Tridion 2011 Sp1

Tags: 2011, core-service, publishing

I am writing a core service to publish the entire pages in a structure group. I have written a recursive method to get all pages in a structure group.

I am loading all pages in a list and publishing them.

I am able to get all pages in a list, but unable to publish them.

My entire code is here.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.Client;
using System.Xml.Linq;
namespace CoreServiceApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static int countPage = 0;
        static List<string> pageArray = new List<string>();
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SessionAwareCoreServiceClient client = new SessionAwareCoreServiceClient("netTcp_2011");
            //get the structure group TCM ID
            Console.Write("Enter TCMID of structure Group:");
            string structureGroupTcmID = Console.ReadLine();
            String targetTcmId = "tcm:0-70-65538";
            Program prog = new Program();
            //Call the recursive method to get all pages in structure group
            prog.PagePublish(structureGroupTcmID, client);
            PublishInstructionData pubData = new PublishInstructionData();
            //convert the pages to string
            string[] pages = pageArray.ToArray();
            //publish
            try
            {
                client.Publish(pages, pubData, new[] { targetTcmId }, PublishPriority.Low, new ReadOptions());
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Publish: Unable to publish Page"+ex.StackTrace, ex);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Total No of Pages" + pages.Length);
            client.Close();
        }

        private void PagePublish(string tcmID, SessionAwareCoreServiceClient client)
        {
            ReadOptions readOptions = new ReadOptions();
            OrganizationalItemItemsFilterData filter = new OrganizationalItemItemsFilterData();
            var elements = client.GetListXml(tcmID, filter);
            foreach (var element in elements.Elements())
            {
               String pageCheck= element.Attribute("ID").Value;
               String specID = pageCheck.Substring(pageCheck.LastIndexOf('-') + 1, 1);
                //check for structure group
                //If structure group call method again
               if (String.Equals(specID, "4"))
               {
                   PagePublish(pageCheck, client);
               }
               //its page
               else
               {
                   pageArray.Add(pageCheck);
               }

            }

        }
    }
}
```

I am getting error while publishing.

The exception is

```
Publish: Unable to publish Page
Server stack trace:
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRunt
ime operation, ProxyRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean on
eway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan tim
eout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCall
Message methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)

Exception rethrown at [0]:
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage req
Msg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgDa
ta, Int32 type)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.Client.ISessionAwareCoreService.Publish
(String[] ids, PublishInstructionData publishInstruction, String[] targets, Null
able`1 priority, ReadOptions readOptions)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.Client.SessionAwareCoreServiceClient.Pu
blish(String[] ids, PublishInstructionData publishInstruction, String[] targets,
 Nullable`1 priority, ReadOptions readOptions)
   at CoreServiceApp.Program.Main(String[] args) in H:\Documents\Visual Studio 2
010\Projects\PagePublish\PagePublish\Program.cs:line 28
Total No of Pages2
```

And the exception message is

```
Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: publishInstruction.ResolveInstruction.
```

Please let me know is there any better way to do this and fix to resolve the exception.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Looks like you need to add a resolve instruction object to your publishing.

I did something similar when I wrote the PagePublish Power tool (you can view the full code here: https://code.google.com/p/tridion-2011-power-tools/source/browse/trunk/PowerTools.Model/Services/PagePublisher.svc.cs)

The main bits you need are:

The call to publish :

```
coreService.Publish(pageIds, GetPublishInstructionData(parameters), parameters.TargetUri, parameters.Priority, new ReadOptions());
```

The second param is an object of `PublishInstructionData`, which is return from the following:

```
private PublishInstructionData GetPublishInstructionData(PagePublisherParameters parameters)
{
    ResolveInstructionData resolveInstruction = new ResolveInstructionData();
    resolveInstruction.IncludeChildPublications = parameters.PublishChildren;
    resolveInstruction.IncludeComponentLinks = parameters.IncludeComponentLinks ? true : false; 
    resolveInstruction.StructureResolveOption = parameters.IncludeStructureGroups ? StructureResolveOption.ItemsAndStructure : StructureResolveOption.OnlyItems;
    resolveInstruction.IncludeWorkflow = parameters.IncludeWorkflow ? true : false;
    resolveInstruction.Purpose = parameters.Republish ? ResolvePurpose.RePublish : ResolvePurpose.Publish;
    RenderInstructionData renderInstruction = new RenderInstructionData();
    renderInstruction.RenderMode = RenderMode.PreviewDynamic;

    PublishInstructionData instruction = new PublishInstructionData();
    instruction.RollbackOnFailure = true;
    instruction.MaximumNumberOfRenderFailures = 1;
    instruction.ResolveInstruction = resolveInstruction;
    instruction.RenderInstruction = renderInstruction;
    return instruction;
}
```

Hope this helps.  It helped me, i've seen a few sketchy bits in the page publisher that need a bit of refactoring :)

Comment: Thank you for replying. Could you also help me to create parameters.

Comment: Editing PublishInstructionData did the job.  PublishInstructionData pubData = new PublishInstructionData
            {
                ResolveInstruction = new ResolveInstructionData() { IncludeChildPublications = true },
                RenderInstruction = new RenderInstructionData()
            };